# Is there a possibility to reschedule a message to be consumed after X minutes in a Redis Stream Consumer

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I have a Redis Stream in which some application sends messages (let's call it "test" stream and "producer" application).
I have a Redis Consumer in a Java Spring Boot application that consumes the message and does some logic with that message. At a given time the message is consumer at T time
Is it possible to make the Redis Consumer re-consumer the message at T + 20 minutes (20 being a configurable value)? I cannot change the producer application to send the message later unfortunately.

Comment: Why do you need to re-consume it after 20 minutes? What happens during this 20 minutes?

Comment: @for_stack Because in theory, the message should be sent from the producer at T + 20 time, but it is sent at T time. But like said, the producer application cannot be changed to send the message when it should.

Comment: Why not to re-post message into stream at T+20 from your own consumer?